# Erro ao traduzir strings antes marcadas como não traduziveis

Tags: android, string, android-studio, tradução

Olá,será que alguem já passou por isso?

Chequei algumas strings como Untranslatable no Editor de Strings do Android Studio somente para agilizar no lançamento.
Nesta atualização, abri novamente o Editor do Android Studio tirei os checks e traduzi normalmente. O problema é que cada vez que vou gerar o apk ele volta e me diz que está marcado com translate=false.
Já fui em cada pastinha das strings e mudei para true, mas nada dá resultado.
Continua o erro ao gerar apk.

Alguém pode me ajudar
Obrigada
Elaine

Answer (score 0):

Pra começar, clique em `Build>Clean project` e tente compilar novamente. As vezes é só limpar os dados do projeto pra resolver algumas paradas no AS.

Como você não mostrou a estrutura das pastas e nenhum código, permita-me sugerir que examine os arquivos de string quanto à localização e formato das definições.

Digamos que o app esteja em inglês (padrão) e português. As pastas e traduções devem seguir este modelo:

```
\SEUAPP\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml

\SEUAPP\app\src\main\res\values-pt\strings.xml
```

No string.xml da pasta value, as strings que não tem tradução seguem este modelo:

```
<string name="app_name" translatable="false">NAME OF APP</string>
```

As que tem tradução seguem este:

```
<string name="app_name">NAME OF APP</string>
```

Não coloque o atributo `translatable="true"` nem outro atributo além de `name`

Na versão traduzida:

```
<string name="app_name">NOME DO APP</string>
```

Verifique os arquivos no editor de código e não de tradução. Compare os arquivos e veja as diferenças.